# Problem related matrix and counting

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, fourier-analysis

I have a following matrix related problem:

Let $F$ be a  $n \times n$ discrete Fourier matrix defined as $F_{j,k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}exp{(\frac{i 2\pi jk}{n})}$, for $0 \leq j,k \leq n$, where $i^2 =-1$.  For $x \in C^n$, let $l(x)$ denote the number of non-zero components of $x.$ Show that for $x \neq 0$

$$l(x)l(Fx) \geq n$$

Note that : $F$ is unitary matrix and $|F_{j,k}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$

Looking for help. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.